# How to create a new window in a speparate thread?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'd like to create a new POPUP style window in a new thread. Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
using namespace Gdiplus;
using namespace std;

const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"Skeleton";
const wchar_t g_szChildClassName[] = L"Child";

wchar_t msgbuf[100];
char msgbuf_ansi[100];
WNDCLASSEX wc;

struct MyStruct
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hWnd;
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    int nCmdShow;
};

MyStruct g_myStruct;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void Example_DrawImage9(HDC hdc) {
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Image image(L"C:/Users/Darek/Fallout2_older/data/art/iface/armor_info.bmp");
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0);
}

int task1(MyStruct myStruct)
{
    sprintf_s(msgbuf_ansi, ("thread\n"));
    OutputDebugStringA(msgbuf_ansi);

    HWND hwnd_child;

    myStruct.wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProcChild;
    myStruct.wc.lpszClassName = g_szChildClassName;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&myStruct.wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"thread - Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd_child = CreateWindowEx(0, g_szChildClassName, L"Child", WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER, 200, 0, 190, 110, myStruct.hWnd, 0, myStruct.hInst, 0);

    swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("THREAD - CHILD -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd_child);
    OutputDebugString(msgbuf);

    if (hwnd_child == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"thread - Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    SetWindowLong(hwnd_child, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd_child, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd_child, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
    ShowWindow(hwnd_child, myStruct.nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd_child);
}
thread t1;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {

        //case WM_KEYDOWN:

    case WM_CLOSE:
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_CLOSE - PARENT \n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        if (MessageBox(hwnd, L"Really quit?", L"My application", MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_DESTROY - PARENT \n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_CREATE: {
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_CREATE - PARENT \n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        thread t1(task1, g_myStruct);
        t1.join();
        return 0;
    }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
int g_fMouseTracking = FALSE;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcChild(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_PAINT:
        HDC hdc;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_PAINT - CHILD -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        Example_DrawImage9(hdc);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        return 0;

        //case WM_KEYDOWN:

    case WM_CREATE: {
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_CREATE - CHILD \n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_MOUSEMOVE - CHILD -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);

        if (!g_fMouseTracking)
        {
            // start tracking if we aren't already
            TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme = {};
            tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
            tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
            tme.hwndTrack = hwnd;
            tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;

            g_fMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
        }

        return 0;

    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_MOUSELEAVE  - CHILD -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd);
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);

        g_fMouseTracking = FALSE; // tracking now canceled

        return 0;

    case WM_CLOSE:
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_CLOSE - CHILD \n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        /*if (MessageBox(hwnd, L"Really quit?", L"My application", MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }*/
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("WM_DESTROY - CHILD \n"));
        OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    //WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    ULONG_PTR token;
    GdiplusStartupInput input = { 0 };
    input.GdiplusVersion = 1;
    GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    g_myStruct.wc = wc;
    
    g_myStruct.hInst = hInstance;
    g_myStruct.nCmdShow = nCmdShow;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, g_szClassName, L"Skeleton", WS_BORDER, 0, 0, 190, 110, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    g_myStruct.hWnd = hwnd;
    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Parent Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    swprintf_s(msgbuf, _T("MAIN - PARENT -  hwnd: %02X\n"), (int)hwnd);
    OutputDebugString(msgbuf);

    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

The problems is that as I've debugged the child window is indeed created but automatically/magically destroyed when the `WndProcChild` returns.

How to correct the code to have it run as expected (the child window stays open until the main is't destroyed)?

Comment: I'm not sure that you really do want to have multi-threaded GUI. Usually when people fully absorb the consequences, they realise that a single GUI thread is what they actually want.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Comment: Agree with @DavidHeffernan. Users aren't that fast. A single core is fast enough to handle all mouse clicks and keyboard presses. Just don't have that UI thread do all the work itself in response to those user actions.

Comment: @DavidHefferman perhaps to have separate message pumps to control parralel processes (nmessage pump controls not only gui, but abd thread-system interaction, or interprocess ) without causing process or gui to lock up. But I'd rather used some framework that does have such functionality rather than rolling it by myself, especially without being keen to read official documentation on their website( this question literally answered in the chapter on threads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread own the window it had created and its message queue and therefore must provide an event loop. It's destroyed because in Win API ownership is treated in RAII way - when owner ceases to exist, so do the acquired objects.

Comment: Resource management in the Windows API is **expressly** manual. Not sure where you got the idea from that this were somehow automatic.